# Size Limit to Priority Queue

Tags: java, collections

add() or offer()The difference is that offer() will return false if it fails to insert the element on a size restricted Queue, whereas add() will throw an IllegalStateException.
But Which Class we have In java which implements Queue and supports size limit? Or Please help me to understand If we can do limit the size Priority Queue.

Comment: I don't think so (`Collections` aren't size restricted); you could implement one.

Comment: a typical example of bounded queue: [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). If you need bounded *priority queue*, you need write your own wrapper for [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Comment: well then what is the max size limit of Priority Queue is it also Integer.MAX_VALUE-5 or don't have any size limit (means will store till we get OutOfMemoryError)?

Comment: One more thing I haven't got with what size it grows for eg. ArrayList grows by 50% , vector just by double of its initial size then what about PriorityQueue.

Comment: @PANKAJDUBEY that's an internal implementation detail not exposed to the user; there's no need to worry about that.

Comment: I found this // Double size if small; else grow by 50%
int newCapacity = ((oldCapacity < 64)?
((oldCapacity + 1) * 2):
((oldCapacity / 2) * 3));